# How can I generate a text using generator in python?

Tags: python, generator

I want to make a text using python generator

I'm a beginner and have started learning python recently , I have searched the web but didn't find anything useful

```
def make_text(n):
    b = ["hello"]
    yield n+b
n = ['how are you', 'what is your name']
for x in range(2):
    title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="title"]')
    title.send_keys(make_text(n))
```

I want to get :

```
hello how are you 
hello what's your name?
```

but i get this error :

```
object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you use `return n+b` instead of `yield n+b`?

Comment: A generator is meant to be used along with iteration over the generator. I don't se that in the code. Your code will not throw that error if you iterate over `make_text()`

Comment: `title.send_keys` checks the `len` of the `argument` passed ? If that is the case, then you can't pass the generator to the `title.send_keys` :). Anyway, why are you using `generator`s for this ?

Comment: @hansolo I want to have "hello how are you " first time that the loop runs and hello what's your name second time

Comment: @reportgunner I want it to be a generator exactly, I don't think it would be a generator without yield

Comment: the generator behaves exactly like a function in your use case. It does not seem like a good fit to use a generator here @nima

Comment: You need to post an [mcve]. Part of that process is eliminating things (like Selenium) that have nothing to do with the error. That will help you narrow down the problem and find your own solution. You could just as easily removed all Selenium references and used `print(make_text(n))` and still repro'd the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic sample of what you can do. You need to iterate the `yield`ed object,

```
def make_text(word):
    greetings = ['how are you', 'what is your name']
    for greet in greetings:
        yield "{} {}".format(word, greet)

def say():
    texts = ['hello',]
    for text in texts:
        x = make_text(text)
        for n in x:
            print(n)
            title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="title"]')
            title.send_keys(n)


say()
```

Output,

```
hello how are you
hello what is your name
```

Answer (score 0):

A more beginner-friendly version of your code would be:

```
def make_text(n):
    b = ["hello"]
    return n + b

words = ['how are you', 'what is your name']

for word in words:
    text = make_text(word)
    print(text)
```